# transpose column headers to rows in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view which looks like this

```
          value1count     value2count value3count
          ----------------------------------------
             25              35          55
```

I need to transpose the column header into rows and so I need it to look like

```
          Values              Count
         -----------------------------
           value1count         25
           value2count         35
           value3count         55
```

I can do this by selecting individual column names as first column and data as second column and then do a union of the same for all columns.

Is there a better way to do this?
I am using PosgreSQL 8.1 and so don't have pivot operators to work with.

Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: yes we are upgrading to the latest version..probably by end of summer....Thanks

Comment: Columns like that (and questions like that) usually indicate a flawed design. You mention a VIEW involved so it might not be the case with your tables. But do consider a re-design if that view reflects the actual table structure

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Crosstab only does the reverse of what you need, but this should help you:

First create the `unnest()` function that is included in 8.4, see [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Unnest) for instructions.

Then you can do this (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql) post):

```
SELECT
   unnest(array['value1Count', 'value2Count', 'value3Count']) AS "Values",
   unnest(array[value1Count, value2Count, value3Count]) AS "Count"
FROM view_name
ORDER BY "Values"
```

I can verify that this works in 8.4, but because I don't have 8.1, I can't promise it will work the same.

Comment: This is brilliant..worked fine in 8.1..my union query took 10 seconds and this unnest query just took 3 seconds..Thanks a lot PinnyM.

Comment: Just tried it in postgresql 11 and it worked out of the box.

Comment: SELECT
   unnest(array['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10','x11','x12','x13','x14','x15','x16']) opciones,
   unnest(array[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16]) marcado
FROM control_xopcion_table
where handler_id = 76 and idemergencia = 2573

Comment: @PinnyM let's say we have more columns that get added to the table in the future so is there a way we can make the arrays to be populated more dynamically?

Comment: @AdarshRavi you can use the hstore approach mentioned in the answer below this one.

Comment: How do I do from the reverse operation of transpose for this example？

Comment: @AkiraChen this is what the crosstab function can help with.

Answer (score 9):

I achieved your goal by using `hstore`'s functionalities :

```
SELECT (x).key, (x).value
FROM
  ( SELECT EACH(hstore(t)) as x
    FROM   t
  ) q;
```

May you have multiple rows in your "to-be-exploded" view or table (referred here as `t`), you might need to insert an additionnal identifier in the intermediate table `q`, for example:

```
SELECT id, (x).key, (x).value
FROM
  ( SELECT id, EACH(hstore(t)) as x
    FROM   t
  ) q;
```

Reference: [`hstore` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html)

Comment: +1, The advantage here is avoiding the need to name your columns in your query.  Apparently [it doesn't perform quite as well as unnest](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/283-Unpivoting-data-in-PostgreSQL.html), but not to a significant degree.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution, thank you! The only problem is that the column ordering gets messed up. Do you have any idea how to work around that?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking to do something similar to this to more easily process table information from a bash script.  Turns out to be very easy to tell psql to display table columns as rows:

```
psql mydbname -x -A -F= -c "select * from blah where id=123"
```

- The `-x` is what pivots the output.
- The `-A` removes extra spacing.
- The `-F=` replaces `|` with `=` between the column name and the value.

This of course wont work in SQL, it only modifies how `psql` happens to format output.

Comment: Thanks! And if you need that behaviour during an interactive psql session, you can use `\x on` or even `\x auto` to switch to that mode whenever output table would be too wide for your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. I wrapped my query in a with statement and then did a bunch of `UNION ALL`s for each row. In my situation, if I had multiple records, the ncm_id would be different, so I went ahead and added that to my column list in my result set. This may not be the best way to do this, but it worked for my use case.

```
 WITH query_a AS (
     SELECT
       fin_item.item_number || ' - ' || fin_item.item_descrip1 fin_item,
       fin_ls.ls_number,
       ls_sort.sortby_employeeid,
       ls_sort.ncm_id,
       ls_sort.created_at,
       ls_sort.updated_at,
       ls_sort.sort_qty,
       ls_sort.initial_scan_time,
       ls_sort.ncm_scan_time,
       ls_sort.badge_scan_time,
       ls_sort.computer_name,
       ls_sort.number_of_ops,
       ls_sort.ncm_item_scan_time,
       sort_by.name sort_by,
       tblncm.instructions,
       tblncm.ncm_comments
     FROM public.item AS fin_item
       INNER JOIN public.ls AS fin_ls ON fin_item.item_id = fin_ls.ls_item_id
       INNER JOIN stone.ls_sort ON fin_ls.ls_id = ls_sort.ls_id
       INNER JOIN stone.vw_mssql_employees AS sort_by ON ls_sort.sortby_employeeid = sort_by.employeeid
       INNER JOIN stone.tblncm ON ls_sort.ncm_id = tblncm.ncm_id
       LEFT JOIN stone.equips AS mach_equips ON ls_sort.mach_equip_id = mach_equips.id
       LEFT JOIN stone.equips AS mold_equips ON ls_sort.mold_equip_id = mold_equips.id
     WHERE 1 = 1
           AND fin_ls.ls_number ILIKE 'S143027526190' || '%'
 )
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     (SELECT 'fin_item' my_column, fin_item::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'ls_number' my_column, ls_number::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'sortby_employeeid' my_column, sortby_employeeid::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'ncm_id' my_column, ncm_id::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'created_at' my_column, created_at::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'updated_at' my_column, updated_at::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'sort_qty' my_column, sort_qty::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'initial_scan_time' my_column, initial_scan_time::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'ncm_scan_time' my_column, ncm_scan_time::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'badge_scan_time' my_column, badge_scan_time::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'computer_name' my_column, computer_name::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'number_of_ops' my_column, number_of_ops::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'ncm_item_scan_time' my_column, ncm_item_scan_time::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'sort_by' my_column, sort_by::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'instructions' my_column, instructions::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 'ncm_comments' my_column, ncm_comments::TEXT my_value, ncm_id::TEXT my_ncm FROM query_a)
   ) as query_guy
 ORDER BY my_ncm;
```

Comment: Very nice example. It would be even better if you modified it to a simplified version compatible with the question's specific case.

Comment: I wonder if query's performance is tied with the UNNEST one.

Answer (score 0):

I could be not understanding...but the way I did this was to also select DISTINCT then select the average columns values I needed. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contributing_factor_vehicle_1, AVG(number_of_cyclist_injured) FROM "table1".motor_vehicle_collisions_crashes 
GROUP BY contributing_factor_vehicle_1
ORDER BY avg(number_of_cyclist_injured) desc
```

That's what created something like so:
[image]

This was NYC motor vehicle crash data btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of using hstore, much like [Mickaël Le Baillif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21132974/1319998), but a little bit more concise, and allows you to choose a subset of the columns dynamically, and shows how you can include more regular "hard coded" columns, like an ID, that tend to be required in more realistic cases.

```sql
-- Example wide data, similar to the question, but with an extra "id" column
WITH example_wide_data("id", "value1count", "value2count", "value3count") AS (
  VALUES 
    (1, 4, 5, 6),
    (2, 8, 9, 10)
)

SELECT
  id,
  r.key AS value_name,
  r.value AS value
FROM
  example_wide_data w,
  each(hstore(w.*)) AS r(key, value)
WHERE
  -- Chooses the columns to transpose dynamically
  -- Difference cases will likely need a different condition
  r.key ~ '^value[0-9]+count$';
```

Note there is a downside to the hstore approach: it casts the values to text along the way, so you might need to cast the values back to another type, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In reading these answers, I feel that using WITH and UNION would be way simpler; No additional functions or stuff:

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM view_name) 
   SELECT val1 FROM tmp UNION
   SELECT val2 FROM tmp UNION
   SELECT val3 FROM tmp;
```