# transform columns to rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I have a table `table1` like below

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | loc  | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | loc1 |   10 | 190  | null |   20 |
|  2 | loc2 |   20 | null | 10   |   10 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
```

need to combine the val1 to val4 into a new column `val` with a row for each so that the output is like below.

NOTE: - I data I have has val1 to val30 -> ie. 30 columns per row that need to be converted into rows.

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | loc  |  val   |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | loc1 |   10   |
|  1 | loc1 |   190  |
|  1 | loc1 |   null |
|  1 | loc1 |   20   |
|  2 | loc2 |   20   |
|  2 | loc2 |   null |
|  2 | loc2 |   10   |
|  2 | loc2 |   10   |
+----+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a classier approach than this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
select id, loc, val1 as val from #t a
UNION ALL
select id, loc, val2 as val from #t a
UNION ALL
select id, loc, val3 as val from #t a
UNION ALL
select id, loc, val4 as val from #t a
) x
order by ID
```

Here's my attempt with unpivot but cant get the nulls, perhaps perform a join for the nulls? Anyway i'll still try

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT * FROM #t
) main
UNPIVOT (
    new_val 
    FOR val IN (val1, val2, val3, val4) 
) unpiv
```

Comment: He has 30 columns (which he again did not tell us).  A better approach might be to use cross tabs.  @a_horse_with_no_name could figure this one out.

Comment: I'm actually trying out the cross join approach right now haha @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Postgres dont support UNPIVOT.

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno - can you look at GurV's comment and possibly fix the second part of the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `cross join` with `generate_series` for this:

```
select
    id,
    loc,
    case x.i
        when 1 then val1 
        when 2 then val2
        . . .
    end as val
from t 
cross join generate_series(1, 4) x (i)
```

It uses the table only once and can be easily extended to accommodate more columns.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/ZEOR87961)

***Note**: In the accepted answer, first approach reads the table many times (as many times as column to be unpivoted) and second approach is wrong as there is no UNPIVOT in postgresql.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use lateral join for transform columns to rows :

```
SELECT a.id,a.loc,t.vals
FROM table1 a,
unnest(ARRAY[a.val1,a.val2,a.val3,a.val4]) t(vals);
```

If you want to this with a dynamic added columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION columns_to_rows(
 out id integer,
 out loc text,
 out vals integer
)
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$body$
DECLARE

columns_to_rows text;

BEGIN

 SELECT string_agg('a.'||attname, ',') into columns_to_rows
 FROM pg_attribute
 WHERE attrelid = 'your_table'::regclass AND --table name
 attnum > 0 and --get just the visible columns
 attname <> all (array [ 'id', 'loc' ]) AND --exclude some columns
 NOT attisdropped ; --column is not dropped

 RETURN QUERY
 EXECUTE format('SELECT a.id,a.loc,t.vals
 FROM your_table a, 
 unnest(ARRAY[%s]) t(vals)',columns_to_rows);

end;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Look at this link for more detail: [Columns to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087244/7689902)

Answer (score 0):

It will not work in postgress as needed by user. Saw when it was mentioned in comments.

I am finding a way to handle "NULL"

```
select p.id,p.loc,CASE WHEN p.val=0 THEN NULL ELSE p.val END AS val
from 
(
    SELECT id,loc,ISNULL(val1,0) AS val1,ISNULL(val2,0) AS val2,ISNULL(val3,0) AS val3,ISNULL(val4,0) AS val4
    FROM Table1
)T
unpivot
(
  val
  for locval in(val1,val2,val3,val4)
)p
```

[Test](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler)

***EDIT:***

Best Solution from my Side:

```
select a.id,a.loc,ex.val
from (select 'val1' as [over] union all select 'val2' union all select 'val3'
        union all select 'val1' ) pmu
cross join (select id,loc from Table1) as a
left join
Table1 pt
unpivot
(
 [val]
 for [over] in (val1, val2, val3, val4)
) ex
on pmu.[over] = ex.[over] and
   a.id = ex.id
```

[Test](http://rextester.com/XJI72840)

Comment: Not SQL Server.