# Select Contents of array or column of another table as row headers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a table: say a metric for places in time series

```
place 1990 1991 1992 1993
NM     23   34   21   43
..     ..   ..   ..   ..
```

The data source table has each year as one row. I need to dynamically create the headers 1990,1991... by looking at the source table and get the metrics there

This is in PostgreSQL

I have created an array of years and trying to "select" years by looping to generate a table. Please see code

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    time varchar;
BEGIN
    FOREACH time IN ARRAY  (select ARRAY_agg(a) from (select year from headers) as a)
    LOOP 
       select time;
    END LOOP;
END;
$do$
```

This code will not run but I would like to see the result equivalent to without having to type the dates as string (they are in another table)

```
select 'jan_1990', 'jan_1991', 'jan_1992' ..
```

Comment: I would say just `UNION` two queries to get that first row there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    time varchar;
BEGIN
    FOREACH time IN ARRAY(//data returned from select)
    LOOP 
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN %s datatype;', btrim(time,'()')); 
        -- brtim was necessary as time is returned as (jan-2019).. with the brackets       
    END LOOP;
END;
$do$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at another post that shows how to transpose:

[PostgreSQL convert columns to rows? Transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084503/postgresql-convert-columns-to-rows-transpose)