# pivot table with multiple value columns in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I need a query which will help me to get data as described below

I have a table as followed

| ID | date | STATUS | TIME09_10 | TIME10_11 | TIME11_12 | TIME12_13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | RUN | 30 | 60 | 45 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | WALK | 15 | 0 | o | 30 |
| 3 | 2021-09-01 | STOP | 15 | 0 | 15 | 30 |

I want this data to be in below format. From the above table , value columns name has to be replaced with hour and join with date column.  I would really appreciate someone’s help.
I am using postgres sql database.

| date & time | run | walk | stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 09:00 | 30 | 15 | 15 |
| 2021-09-01 10:00 | 60 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-09-01 11:00 | 45 | 0 | 15 |
| 2021-09-01 12:00 | 0 | 30 | 30 |

Comment: This might be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/q/14084503/5668956

Comment: I have tried the suggested solution but it did not give expected out out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `crosstab(source_sql text, category_sql text)` function. You need to install the `tablefunc` extension:

```sql
create extension if not exists tablefunc;
```

Read about the extension [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html)

The function expects data in the three-column format `(row_name, category, value)`. In this case they are `date+time`, `status` and `duration`.

```sql
select 
    date+ '8 hour'::interval+ '1 hour'::interval* i as hour,
    status,
    (array[time09_10, time10_11, time11_12, time12_13])[i] as duration
from my_table
cross join generate_series(1, 4) i
```

```
        hour         | status | duration
---------------------+--------+----------
 2021-09-01 09:00:00 | RUN    |       30
 2021-09-01 09:00:00 | WALK   |       15
 2021-09-01 09:00:00 | STOP   |       15
 2021-09-01 10:00:00 | RUN    |       60
 2021-09-01 10:00:00 | WALK   |        0
 2021-09-01 10:00:00 | STOP   |        0
 2021-09-01 11:00:00 | RUN    |       45
 2021-09-01 11:00:00 | WALK   |        0
 2021-09-01 11:00:00 | STOP   |       15
 2021-09-01 12:00:00 | RUN    |        0
 2021-09-01 12:00:00 | WALK   |       30
 2021-09-01 12:00:00 | STOP   |       30
(12 rows)
```

Pass the query as the first argument to the function:

```sql
select *
from crosstab(
    $source$
        select 
            date+ '8 hour'::interval+ '1 hour'::interval* i as hour,
            status,
            (array[time09_10, time10_11, time11_12, time12_13])[i] as duration
        from my_table
        cross join generate_series(1, 4) i
    $source$,
    $category$
        values('RUN'), ('STOP'), ('WALK')
    $category$
) as (hour timestamp, run int, stop int, walk int)
```

```
        hour         | run | stop | walk
---------------------+-----+------+------
 2021-09-01 09:00:00 |  30 |   15 |   15
 2021-09-01 10:00:00 |  60 |    0 |    0
 2021-09-01 11:00:00 |  45 |   15 |    0
 2021-09-01 12:00:00 |   0 |   30 |   30
(4 rows)
```

There is a nice alternative if you do not want to use the extension. Convert the first query results to the expected output with the `jsonb` function:

```sql
select 
    hour, 
    (activities->>'RUN')::int as run,
    (activities->>'STOP')::int as stop,
    (activities->>'WALK')::int as walk
from (
    select hour, jsonb_object_agg(status, duration) as activities
    from (
        select 
            date+ '8 hour'::interval+ '1 hour'::interval* i as hour,
            status,
            (array[time09_10, time10_11, time11_12, time12_13])[i] as duration
        from my_table
        cross join generate_series(1, 4) i
        ) s
    group by hour
    ) s
order by hour
```

Test the `jsonb` solution in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5a494d23d1f2f464c94f0c0a33ef6608)