# How to rotate a two-column table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, dynamic-sql, crosstab

This might be a novice question – I'm still learning. I'm on PostgreSQL 9.6 with the following query:

```
SELECT locales, count(locales) FROM (
    SELECT lower((regexp_matches(locale, '([a-z]{2,3}(-[a-z]{2,3})?)', 'i'))[1]) 
    AS locales FROM users) 
AS _ GROUP BY locales
```

My query returns the following dynamic rows:

| locales | count |
| --- | --- |
| en | 10 |
| fr | 7 |
| de | 3 |
| n additional locales (~300)... | n-count |

I'm trying to rotate it so that locale values end up as columns with a single row, like this:

| en | fr | de | n additional locales (~300)... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 | 3 | n-count |

I'm having to do this to play nice with a time-series db/app

I've tried using `crosstab()`, but all the examples show better defined tables with 3 or more columns.

I've looked at examples using `join`, but I can't figure out how to do it dynamically.

Comment: Please *always* disclose your version of Postgres up front.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter – I added this detail.

Comment: Postgres 9.6 has reached EOL last year. Upgrade to a current version! https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: If only I had privileges – it's managed by another team.  I will nudge them tho ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Base query

In Postgres 10 or later you could use the simpler and faster [`regexp_match()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) instead of `regexp_matches()`. (Since you only take the first match per row anyway.) But don't bother and use the even simpler `substring()` instead:

```sql
SELECT lower(substring(locale, '(?i)[a-z]{2,3}(?:-[a-z]{2,3})?')) AS locale
     , count(*)::int AS ct
FROM   users
WHERE  locale ~* '[a-z]{2,3}'  -- eliminate NULL, allow index support
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC, 1
```

Simpler and faster than your original base query.

About those ordinal numbers in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Subtle difference: `regexp_matches()` returns *no row* for no match, while `substring()` returns `null`. I added a `WHERE` clause to eliminate non-matches a-priori - and allow index support if applicable, but I don't expect indexes to help here.

Note the prefixed `(?i)`, that's a so-called ["embedded option"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-METASYNTAX) to use case-insensitive matching.

Added a deterministic `ORDER BY` clause. You'd need that for a simple `crosstab()`.

Aside: you might need `_` in the pattern instead of `-` for locales like "en_US".

### Pivot

Try as you might, SQL does not allow dynamic result columns in a single query. You need two round trips to the server. See;

- [How do I generate a pivoted CROSS JOIN where the resulting table definition is unknown?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159286/3684)

You **can** use a dynamically generated `crosstab()` query. Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Dynamic query:

- [PostgreSQL convert columns to rows? Transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084503/postgresql-convert-columns-to-rows-transpose/14087244#14087244)

**But** since you generate **a single row** of plain integer values, I suggest a simple approach:

```sql
SELECT 'SELECT ' || string_agg(ct || ' AS ' || quote_ident(locale), ', ')
FROM  (
   SELECT lower(substring(locale, '(?i)[a-z]{2,3}(?:-[a-z]{2,3})?')) AS locale
        , count(*)::int AS ct
   FROM   users
   WHERE  locale ~* '[a-z]{2,3}'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 2 DESC, 1
   ) t
```

Generates a query of the form:

```
SELECT 10 AS en, 7 AS fr, 3 AS de, 3 AS "de-at"
```

Execute it to produce your desired result.

In psql you can append `\gexec` to the generating query to feed the generated SQL string back to the server immediately. See:

- [My function returned a string. How to execute it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300700/3684)

Comment: Using psql locally, this answer works like a charm (thanks also for optimizing the base query)!  However, since this is executed within the context of a plugin, I'm not able to use `\gexec`.  I believe using `crosstab()` avoids needing exec command, is that correct?

Comment: I tried wrapping my base query in `crosstab()` but can't get the syntax right despite the links you provided.  Would you be willing/able to expand on your answer to include the `crosstab()` solution with correct syntax?

Comment: `crosstab()` would be overkill for this task. If you need a `crosstab()` solution (do you really?), start a new question targeting that specifically, and be sure to provide a fiddle with sample data to go with it. Is *this* question answered properly?