# Column values as rows in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, unpivot

I have a table called price and it has columns like Item , Price_01, Price_02, Price_03, Price_04
and table data is as follows.

```
Item , Price_01, Price_02, Price_03, Price_04
Bat  , 1000 , 1100, 1200 , 1300
Ball  , 11000 , 1200, 1300 , 1400
```

My requirement is, i want to get Price columns data as rows for the given input Item.
For example, Item input is Bat then output should be like

```
1000
1100
1200
1300
```

How can i do this in Postgres. Is there any alternate for PIVOT in Postgres

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL convert columns to rows? Transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084503/postgresql-convert-columns-to-rows-transpose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an UNPIVOT, not PIVOT and it can be done using a VALUES clause in Postgres:

```
select p.item, 
       v.price
from price p
  cross join lateral (
     values (p.price_01), (p.price_02), (p.price_03), (p.price_04) 
  ) as v(price)
where p.item = 'Bat'
```