# How to create a pivot table by product by month in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, crosstab

I have 3 tables:

```
users (id, account_balance)
grocery (user_id, date, amount_paid)
fishmarket (user_id, date, amount_paid)
```

Both fishmarket and grocery tables may have multiple occurrences for the same user_id with different dates and amounts paid or have nothing at all for any given user. I am trying to develop a pivot table of the following structure:

```
id | grocery_amount_paid_January | fishmarket_amount_paid_January
  1          10                           NULL
  2          40                           71
```

The only idea I can come with is to create multiple left joins, but this should be wrong since there will be 24 joins (per each month) for each product. Is there a better way?

Comment: If MS SQL look at PIVOT and UNPIVOT

Comment: @RyanBostwick in PostgreSQL you have `crosstab`

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql

Comment: You are unclear about what you want. Please provide a complete example result. One column per month? or one row per id and month? Fishmarket and Grocery in one table? so 24 columns + `id`? or 12 rows per `id`?

Comment: @Erwin there should be 24 columns (for each product per each month) + id. Fishmarket and Grocery are different tables. Does it clarify?

Comment: @RyanBostwick: It does. I already whipped up an answer for the other variant. You may still like it ..

Answer (score 4):

I have provided a lot of answers on [crosstab queries in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[crosstab]+[postgresql]+is%3Aanswer) lately. Sometimes a "plain" query like the following does the job:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT '2012-01-01'::date AS _from
                 ,'2012-12-01'::date As _to)  -- provide date range once in CTE
SELECT u.id
      ,to_char(m.mon, 'MM.YYYY') AS month_year
      ,g.amount_paid AS grocery_amount_paid
      ,f.amount_paid AS fishmarket_amount_paid
FROM   users u
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT generate_series(_from, _to, '1 month') AS mon FROM x) m 
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id
         ,date_trunc('month', date) AS mon
         ,sum(amount_paid) AS amount_paid
   FROM   x, grocery                        -- CROSS JOIN with a single row
   WHERE  date >= _from
   AND    date <  (_to + interval '1 month')
   GROUP  BY 1,2
   ) g ON g.user_id = u.id AND m.mon = g.mon
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id
         ,date_trunc('month', date) AS mon
         ,sum(amount_paid) AS amount_paid
   FROM   x, fishmarket
   WHERE  date >= _from
   AND    date <  (_to + interval '1 month')
   GROUP  BY 1,2
   ) f ON f.user_id = u.id AND m.mon = g.mon
ORDER  BY u.id, m.mon;
```

produces this output:

```
id | month_year | grocery_amount_paid | fishmarket_amount_paid
---+------------+---------------------+------------------------
 1 | 01.2012    | 10                  | NULL
 1 | 02.2012    | NULL                | 65
 1 | 03.2012    | 98                  | 13
...
 2 | 02.2012    | 40                  | 71
 2 | 02.2012    | NULL                | NULL
```

#### Major points

- The first CTE is for convenience only. So you have to type your date range once only. You can use *any* date range - as long as it's dates with the first of the month (rest of the month will be included!). You could add [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to it, but I guess you can keep the urge to use invalid dates in check.
- First [`CROSS JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) users to the result of [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) (`m`) which provides one row per month in your date range. You have learned [in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860) how that results in multiple rows per user.
- The two subqueries are identical twins. Use `WHERE` clauses that operate on the base column, so it can utilize an index - which you should have if your table runs over many years (no use for only one or two years, a sequential scan will be faster):

  ```
  CREATE INDEX grocery_date ON grocery (date);
  ```
- Then reduce all dates to the first of the month with [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) and sum `amount_paid` per `user_id` and the resulting `mon`.
- `LEFT JOIN` the result to the base table, again by `user_id` and the resulting `mon`. This way, rows are neither multiplied nor dropped. You get one row per `user_id` and month. Voilá.

BTW, I'd never use a column name `id`. Call it `user_id` in the table `users` as well.