# PostgreSQL columns to rows with no explicilty specifying column names / columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-processing

I would like to know is there any way to do unpivot (turn columns to rows) data in PostgreSQL.

For example, if I have a table like:

```
ID   Name    Age
1    Alice    16
2    Bob      21
3    Carl     18
```

I want to get an output like

```
ID   Column_Name Column_Value
1    Name        Alice
1    Age         16
2    Name        Bob
2    Age         21
3    Name        Carl
3    Age         18
```

I know I could do it like ([**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/513fe/4) with data to try it):

```
select
   U.ID,
   unnest(array['Name', 'Age']) as Column_Name,
   unnest(array[U.Name, U.Age::text]) as Column_Value
from Users as U
```

But is there any way I could do it for all columns in table without explicitly specifying column names?
For example, for SQL Server I know of at least 2 ways to do it - dynamic SQL or turn data into xml and parse xml - [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows). May be there's some xml trick in PostgreSQL too?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql  this explain how to unpivot using UNION ALL

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want explicitly specify columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hstore` extension:

```
SELECT id, skeys(hstore(users)) AS column, svals(hstore(users)) AS value FROM users;
```