# PostgreSQL, find strings differ by n characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a table like this

```
id  data
1   0001
2   1000
3   2010
4   0120
5   0020
6   0002
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fb131/1)

`id` is primary key, `data` is fixed length string where characters could be 0, 1, 2.

Is there a way to build an index so I could quickly find strings which are differ by n characters from given string? like for string `0001` and `n = 1` I want to get row 6.

Thanks.

Comment: With `n = 1` you should only find row 6. row 2 and 5 differ in two places.

Comment: oops corrected, thanks @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: If n = 2 then ids will be 3 & 4?

Comment: @Roms it should be 5 and 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [`levenshtein()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/fuzzystrmatch.html#AEN140765) function, provided by the additional module [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/fuzzystrmatch.html). It does exactly what you are asking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  levenshtein(data, '1110') = 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fb131/4)

But it is not very fast. Slow with big tables, because it can't use an index.

You might get somewhere with the *similarity* or *distance* operators provided by the additional module [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html). Those can use a trigram index as detailed in the linked manual pages. I did not get anywhere, the module is using a different definition of "similarity".

Generally the problem seems to fit in the [KNN ("k nearest neighbours") search pattern](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/talks/pgcon-2010-1.pdf).

If your case is as simple as the example in the question, you can use `LIKE` in combination with a trigram GIN index, which should be reasonably fast with big tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  data <> '1110'
AND   (data LIKE '_110' OR
       data LIKE '1_10' OR
       data LIKE '11_0' OR
       data LIKE '111_');
```

Obviously, this technique quickly becomes unfeasible with longer strings and more than `1` difference.

**However**, since the string is so short, any query will match a rather big percentage of the base table. Therefore, index support will hardly buy you anything. Most of the time it will be faster for Postgres to scan sequentially.

I tested with 10k and 100k rows with and without a trigram GIN index. Since ~ 19% match the criteria for the given test case, a sequential scan is faster and `levenshtein()` still wins. For more selective queries matching less than around 5 % of the rows (depends), a query using an index is (much) faster.

Comment: yeah, I've though abount levenshtein, but I suppose it's not very fast :( I'm checking trigrams now