# Transform database columns to rows and sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm building a system where I have to find the combined price of a computer system by using the database data. The first screenshot is a build from the system table.

**Systems Table**
[image]

**Parts Table**

[image]

The different kinds are: motherboard, case, ram, cpu, graphic.
What I need is some way of turning the columns into rows and thereby summing the prices of each system.

Here is the table and content.

```
CREATE TABLE Component ( 
        nome VARCHAR(30), 
        kind VARCHAR(10), /*cpu, ram, mainboard, cases*/
        price INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(nome)
    );

CREATE TABLE Computer_system ( 
        nome VARCHAR(30),
        ram VARCHAR(20),
        cpu VARCHAR(20),
        mainboard VARCHAR(20),
        cases VARCHAR(20),
        gfx VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY(nome)
    );


INSERT INTO Computer_system VALUES('SERVER1','D31','XEON1','LGA2011_D3_E_OGFX','CASE_A',null); 
INSERT INTO Computer_system VALUES('SERVER2','D43','XEON3','LGA2011_D4_E_OGFX','CASE_A',null);
INSERT INTO Computer_system VALUES('CONSUMER1','D43','I71','LGA1150_D4_ATX_OGFX','CASE_B',null); 
INSERT INTO Computer_system VALUES('GAMING1', 'D51', 'FX','AM3+_D5_ATX','BLACK_PEARL', 'NVIDIA_TITAN_BLACK_X');
INSERT INTO Computer_system VALUES('BUDGETO', 'D31', 'XEON1','LGA2011_D3_ATX','CASE_B', null);
```

Comment: Please don't paste important details in graphics - I can't see them (blocked at work). Also, if I want to cut/paste to duplicate your setup, I can't. Putting actual code table definitions would be better, or create an SQLFiddle

Comment: The graphics were links but was changed på @Anant Dabhi to images :).

Comment: If I post the create table etc. would you look at a it @Turophile?

Comment: If you had posted the DDL I would have already seen it. If you do it now I will try to help, but don't forget everyone here is just giving up our time to help others. Try to make it as easy for us as you can.

Comment: @Turophile I've done my best now :). And thanks a lot for spending your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a neat trick for unpivot in Postgres [using UNNEST( ARRAY( ...) )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql)

This efficiently (in one pass of the table) unpivots those multiple columns of table computer_system into multiple rows of (in this case) 3 columns: "nome", "colkind" and "colnome". An example of the unpivoted data:

```
|      nome |   colkind |              colnome |
|-----------|-----------|----------------------|
|   BUDGETO |       ram |                  D31 |
|   BUDGETO |       gfx |               (null) |
|   BUDGETO |     cases |               CASE_B |
|   BUDGETO | mainboard |       LGA2011_D3_ATX |
|   BUDGETO |       cpu |                XEON1 |
```

Once that data is available in that format it is simple to join to the Components table, like this:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      /* this "unpivots" the source data */
      SELECT
           nome
         , unnest(array[ram, cpu, mainboard,cases,gfx]) AS colnome
         , unnest(array['ram', 'cpu', 'mainboard','cases','gfx']) AS colkind
      FROM Computer_system
      ) unpiv
INNER JOIN Components c ON unpiv.colnome = c.nome AND unpiv.colkind = c.kind
;
```

From here it is simple to arrive at this result:

```
|      nome | sum_price |
|-----------|-----------|
|   BUDGETO |       291 |
|   GAMING1 |       515 |
| CONSUMER1 |       292 |
|   SERVER1 |       285 |
|   SERVER2 |       289 |
```

using:

```
SELECT
      unpiv.nome, sum(c.price) sum_price
FROM (
      /* this "unpivots" the source data */
      SELECT
           nome
         , unnest(array[ram, cpu, mainboard,cases,gfx]) AS colnome
         , unnest(array['ram', 'cpu', 'mainboard','cases','gfx']) AS colkind
      FROM Computer_system
      ) unpiv
INNER JOIN Components c ON unpiv.colnome = c.nome AND unpiv.colkind = c.kind
GROUP BY
      unpiv.nome
;
```

<kbd>See this SQLfiddle demo</kbd> & please take note of the execution plan

```
QUERY PLAN
HashAggregate (cost=487.00..488.00 rows=100 width=82)
-> Hash Join (cost=23.50..486.50 rows=100 width=82)
Hash Cond: ((((unnest(ARRAY[computer_system.ram, computer_system.cpu, computer_system.mainboard, computer_system.cases, computer_system.gfx])))::text = (c.nome)::text) AND ((unnest('{ram,cpu,mainboard,cases,gfx}'::text[])) = (c.kind)::text))
-> Seq Scan on computer_system (cost=0.00..112.00 rows=20000 width=368)
-> Hash (cost=15.40..15.40 rows=540 width=120)
-> Seq Scan on components c (cost=0.00..15.40 rows=540 width=120)
```

Comment: Would this work if the key was an `int` column, or a compound (`nome` + `kind`) column?

Comment: I don't see why not, but if this is the situation it woild have been best to represent it in your sample data. Words don't work too well for describing data in my experience :)

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need break down your table design into 3 table, there are Component, Computer_System and Computer_component. Below are the field list:
Computer_System -> computer_id and name
Component -> nome_component, kind, price
Computer_Component -> computer_id, nome_component. With that table, you can sum the total price for each computer_id by join the Computer_System a JOIN Computer Component b ON a.computer_id = b.Computer id JOIN Component c ON b.nome_component = c.nome_component

Comment: I want to try doing it without breaking it down and only using two tables :/.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply with joining `Computer_system` table with `Component` `for each kind` like below query:

```
select c.nome as name,
  (coalesce(ram.price,0)
   +coalesce(cpu.price,0)
   +coalesce(+mainboard.price,0)
   +coalesce(cases.price,0)
   +coalesce(gfx.price,0)) as price
from Computer_system c
left join Components ram on c.ram=ram.nome
left join Components cpu on c.cpu=cpu.nome
left join Components mainboard on c.mainboard=mainboard.nome
left join Components cases on c.cases=cases.nome
left join Components gfx on c.gfx=gfx.nome
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/228d7/13)

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky to do because your table structures aren't suited to this type of query. Also, it is not flexible in case you want more than one `gfx` in a build.

Here is my suggested answer:

```
select sum(price)
from components
where nome in (
  select ram from computer_system where nome = 'GAMING1'
  UNION ALL 
  select cpu from computer_system where nome = 'GAMING1'
  UNION ALL 
  select mainboard from computer_system where nome = 'GAMING1'
  UNION ALL 
  select cases from computer_system where nome = 'GAMING1'
  UNION ALL 
  select gfx from computer_system where nome = 'GAMING1'
  )
;
```

And here it is in a working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/228d7/8

If I restructured the tables, I would make them something like in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f4ed06/1   with and extra `parts_list` table:

```
CREATE TABLE parts_list (
  system_nome VARCHAR(30),
  component_kind VARCHAR(10),
  component_nome VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (system_nome, component_kind, component_nome)
  );
```

and your query for the cost of the GAMING1 system becomes much simpler:

```
select sum(price)
from components as c 
inner join parts_list as PL ON c.kind = pl.component_kind and c.nome = pl.component_nome
where pl.system_nome = 'GAMING1'
;
```