# Count for each record within table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (stu_grades) that stores student data and their grades at the centers they attended

I want to find out how many times for e.g. each student in that table got 'A' and then 'B' etc at any center

stu_grades

```
 stu_ID|grade1|grade2|Grade3|center
    1        A      A     C    1
    2        B      B     B    2
    3        C      C     A    1
    1        C      A     C    2
```

the same student could occur more than once in the table with the same grades or even a different grade, same or different center

I especially want to check where the grade has appeared more than 3 or more times and how many centeres they exist in

So  the final output should be like:

```
Stu_ID|Grade|Count|centercount
1       A      3       2 (As they accquired 'A' from 2 centres)
1       C      3       2 
2       B      3       1 (As they only exist in 1 centre)
3       C      2       1 
3       A      1       1
```

Comment: If you unpivot the data this would be a simple aggregation.  Is the data stored in this pivoted fashion somewhere?  or perhaps use the Unnest function described in this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql

Comment: @xQbert can you help me understand these functions.. how do i make them relevant to my scenario

Comment: I have edited the question slightly so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should satisfy your requirement:

```
SELECT [Stud_ID], Grade, count(*) as GradeCount FROM
  (SELECT [Stud_ID],Grade1 as Grade from [Stud_Details]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Stud_ID],Grade2 as Grade from [Stud_Details]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Stud_ID],Grade3 as Grade from [Stud_Details]) AS T
   GROUP BY T.[Stud_ID],T.Grade
   ORDER BY T.[Stud_ID]
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use `HAVING` after `GROUP BY` to get `gradeCount` which are greater than **3**.

```
SELECT [Stud_ID], Grade, count(*) as GrdCountStud FROM
  (SELECT [Stud_ID],Grade1 as Grade from [Stud_Details]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Stud_ID],Grade2 as Grade from [Stud_Details]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Stud_ID],Grade3 as Grade from [Stud_Details]) AS T
   GROUP BY T.[Stud_ID],T.Grade
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 3   
   ORDER BY T.[Stud_ID]
```

Comment: great that works... is there a way i can limit the count so see how many are more than 3 for e.g?

Comment: Please use valid standard SQL. `[dbo].[Stud_Details]` is an invalid identifier in (standard) SQL (and Postgres)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes Sir! Rightly pointed. I have updated the answer.

Comment: `[Stud_Details]` is also invalid standard SQL

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `union all` to unpivot the different grades into one column and then doing an aggregation.

```
select stu_id,grade,count(*) cnt 
from (
select stu_id,grade_1 grade from stu_grades
union all
select stu_id,grade_2 grade from stu_grades
union all
select stu_id,grade_3 grade from stu_grades
) t
group by stu_id,grade
```

Comment: it says grade doesnt exist?

Comment: `grade` is a column alias defined in the derived table. you shouldn't get that error if you used the exact query from the answer.