# Convert a single row into multiple rows by the columns in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, unpivot

I have a table `cash_drawer` which stores quantity for each denomination of currency for each day at day end:

```
cash_drawer(
    date DATE,
    100 SMALLINT,
    50 SMALLINT,
    20 SMALLINT,
    10 SMALLINT,
    5 SMALLINT,
    1 SMALLINT
)
```

Now any given day, I wish to get each denomination as a row.

If lets say for day `2016-11-25`, if we have the following row:

```
+------------+-------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
| date       |  100  |  50  |  20  |  10  |  5  |  1  |
+------------+-------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
| 2016-11-25 |   5   |  12  |  27  |  43  | 147 | 129 |
+------------+-------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
```

Now I wish to get the out put of the query as:

```
+------------+--------+
|denomination|quantity|
+------------+--------+
|100         |5       |
+------------+--------+
|50          |12      |
+------------+--------+
|20          |27      |
+------------+--------+
|10          |43      |
+------------+--------+
|5           |147     |
+------------+--------+
|1           |129     |
+------------+--------+
```

Is there a method by which this is possible? If you have any other suggestion please be free to suggest.

Comment: check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6360077/3470178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
select key as denomination, value as quantity
from cash_drawer c,
lateral json_each(row_to_json(c))
where key <> 'date'
and date = '2016-11-25';

 denomination | quantity 
--------------+----------
 100          | 5
 50           | 12
 20           | 27
 10           | 43
 5            | 147
 1            | 129
(6 rows)
```

[Test it here.](http://rextester.com/BOLH24099)

Comment: but how do I select for a specific `date`?  do I use `WHERE "date" = '2016-11-25'` after `from cash_drawer c`?

Comment: Of course, you can freely filter the data in `where` clause. See the edited answer.