# Rewrite code with UNPIVOT from sql to redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, unpivot

I have SQL server script that needs to be converted to redshift.

I converted part of it

Here is part of the script where I have a problem with.

```
    SELECT  a.*,
        b.*

FROM    (

SELECT  u.ContactId,
        u.Description,
        CONVERT(Float,u.SeatCharge) AS SeatCharge
        --CAST(u.SeatCharge AS numeric (18,4)) AS SeatCharge,
        --CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), u.SeatCharge)) = 1 then CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), u.SeatCharge) else 0 End)

FROM(

SELECT  md.contactid,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7172 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Core,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7182 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_RCM,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7192 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Advanced_RCM,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7183 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Payroll,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7184 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_DXM,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7185 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Messaging,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7186 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Tasks,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7173 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_Core,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7187 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_Data_Collection,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7189 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_Auditing_Tools,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7190 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_Group_Sessions,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7191 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_ABC_Data,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7211 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_AGA,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 4495 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS LMS_Core,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7175 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS HRIS_PTO,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 8106 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS LMS_Course_Groups,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 8286 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Reach_Me,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 8999 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Redshift,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 9155 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS HRIS_Benefits,
                CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 9156 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS HRIS_Assets
        FROM    public.contact_meta md
        WHERE   md.fieldid IN (4495,7172,7182,7192,7183,7184,7185,7186,7173,7187,7189,7190,7191,7175,7211,7212,8106,8286,8999,9155,9156)
                --AND md.ContactId = 75337
        GROUP BY
                md.contactid
                )s

--UNPIVOT
--(
--SeatCharge
--FOR Description IN (
  --      PM_Core,
    --    PM_RCM,
      --  PM_Advanced_RCM,
       -- PM_Payroll,
       -- PM_DXM,
       -- PM_Messaging,
       -- PM_Tasks,

        --HRIS_Assets)
--)u



WHERE           u.SeatCharge <> ''

        )a
```

All is working, instead of UNPIVOT function.

As I know redshift doesn't have UNPIVOT function.

So now I need to rewrite it correctly?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `UNNEST(ARRAY(...))` approach, borrowed from this [approach by @Stew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360077/1422451) from the PostgreSQL dialect which RedShift originally derives. Specifically, first call `UNNEST` on array of string literal names of columns and then again on array of actual columns to return indicator and value in separate rows.

```
SELECT  s.ContactId,
        UNNEST(ARRAY('PM_Core', 'PM_RCM', 'PM_Advanced_RCM', 'PM_Payroll', 'PM_DXM', 
                     'PM_Messaging', 'PM_Tasks', 'Clinical_Core', 'Clinical_Data_Collection',  
                     'Clinical_Auditing_Tools', 'Clinical_Group_Sessions', 'Clinical_Group_Sessions', 
                     'Clinical_ABC_Data', 'Clinical_AGA', 'LMS_Core', 'HRIS_PTO', 'LMS_Course_Groups',
                     'PM_Reach_Me', 'PM_Redshift', 'HRIS_Benefits', 'HRIS_Assets')) AS Description,
        UNNEST(ARRAY(PM_Core, PM_RCM, PM_Advanced_RCM, PM_Payroll, PM_DXM, 
                     PM_Messaging, PM_Tasks, Clinical_Core, Clinical_Data_Collection,  
                     Clinical_Auditing_Tools, Clinical_Group_Sessions, Clinical_Group_Sessions, 
                     Clinical_ABC_Data, Clinical_AGA, LMS_Core, HRIS_PTO, LMS_Course_Groups,
                     PM_Reach_Me, PM_Redshift, HRIS_Benefits, HRIS_Assets)) AS SeatCharge    
FROM
   (SELECT md.contactid,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7172 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Core,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7182 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_RCM,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7192 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Advanced_RCM,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7183 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Payroll,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7184 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_DXM,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7185 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Messaging,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7186 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Tasks,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7173 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_Core,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7187 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_Data_Collection,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7189 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_Auditing_Tools,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7190 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_Group_Sessions,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7191 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_ABC_Data,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7211 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS Clinical_AGA,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 4495 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS LMS_Core,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 7175 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS HRIS_PTO,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 8106 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS LMS_Course_Groups,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 8286 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Reach_Me,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 8999 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS PM_Redshift,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 9155 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS HRIS_Benefits,
           CONVERT(float, MAX(CASE WHEN md.fieldid= 9156 THEN CONVERT(float,Value) ELSE 0 END)) AS HRIS_Assets
   FROM    public.contact_meta md
   WHERE   md.fieldid IN (4495,7172,7182,7192,7183,7184,7185,7186,7173,7187,7189,7190,7191,7175,7211,7212,8106,8286,8999,9155,9156)
   --AND   md.ContactId = 75337
   GROUP BY
           md.contactid
   ) s
```

[Random Data Demo](http://rextester.com/ARFR20233)

---

However, reconsider pivoting and then unpivoting. Simply create your metric column conditionally with `CASE` and then aggregate:

```
SELECT sub.contactid, sub.Description, MAX(sub."VALUE") As SeatCharge
FROM
       (SELECT md.contactid,
               CASE md.fieldid
                    WHEN 7172 THEN 'PM_Core'
                    WHEN 7182 THEN 'PM_RCM'
                    WHEN 7192 THEN 'PM_Advanced_RCM'
                    WHEN 7183 THEN 'PM_Payroll'
                    WHEN 7184 THEN 'PM_DXM'
                    WHEN 7185 THEN 'PM_Messaging'
                    WHEN 7186 THEN 'PM_Tasks'
                    WHEN 7173 THEN 'Clinical_Core'
                    WHEN 7187 THEN 'Clinical_Data_Collection'
                    WHEN 7189 THEN 'Clinical_Auditing_Tools'
                    WHEN 7190 THEN 'Clinical_Group_Sessions'
                    WHEN 7191 THEN 'Clinical_ABC_Data'
                    WHEN 7211 THEN 'Clinical_AGA'
                    WHEN 4495 THEN 'LMS_Core'
                    WHEN 7175 THEN 'HRIS_PTO'
                    WHEN 8106 THEN 'LMS_Course_Groups'
                    WHEN 8286 THEN 'PM_Reach_Me'
                    WHEN 8999 THEN 'PM_Redshift'
                    WHEN 9155 THEN 'HRIS_Benefits'
                    WHEN 9156 THEN 'HRIS_Assets'
                    ELSE NULL
               END AS Description,
               CONVERT(float, Value) AS VALUE
       FROM    public.contact_meta md
       WHERE   md.fieldid IN (4495, 7172, 7182, 7192, 7183, 7184,7185, 7186, 7173, 7187, 7189,
                              7190, 7191, 7175, 7211, 7212,8106, 8286, 8999, 9155, 9156)
       --AND   md.ContactId = 75337
       ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.contactid, sub.Description
```

NOTE: In future, be sure to incorporate a lookup table of *Description* values that you can join these ids to and avoid the long `CASE` logic calculation and even long `IN` clause.

Comment: Hm. I get this error `[42601][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "'PM_Core'" Position: 108;`

Comment: @EugeneSukh [Unsupported PostgreSQL Features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html): *Array constructors* - that's one of the reasons Redshift questions should not be tagged with postgresql

Comment: @EugeneSukh ... an ANSI SQL alternative is many `UNION` statements for each column.

Comment: So how I need to rewrite it correctly, using UNION?

Comment: Okay. so how I need to rewrite this part, to make it work in Redashift? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Simply avoid the conditional aggregation that pivoted in the first place requiring your unpivot process. Just aggregate with a conditional *Description* column from a long `CASE` statement. See edit with note.

Comment: Thanks for help dude

Comment: Great! Glad to help.