# how to extract source table and insert into target table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that extracts and transforms data from a table and then insert those data into target table and that whole table data should be in single column in target table.below is the query I wrote

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (column1, column2) VALUES
((SELECT * FROM Table1), "seqno");
```

Table 1

```
id  | ename  | email  |  country     |
------------------------------------------------
1     d          ..        ..    
2     v          ..        ..      
3     s          ..        ..
4     n          ..        ..
```

Expected output:

in table2

```
src_data  |  src_column  |  seqno  | objectname
-------------------------------------------------
1             eid            1       coustomer master
2             eid            2       coustomer master        
3             eid            3       coustomer master
4             eid            4       coustomer master
d             ename          1       coustomer master
v             ename          2       coustomer master
s             ename          3       coustomer master
n             ename          4       coustomer master
email1        email          1       coustomer master
email2        email          2       coustomer master
email3        email          3       coustomer master
email4        email          4       coustomer master
country1      country        1       coustomer master
country2      country        2       coustomer master
country3      country        3       coustomer master
country4      country        4       coustomer master
```

How can I achieve this?

Please help me to rectify this

Comment: What DB are you using? What you want to do is called UNPIVOT. Not all RDBMS support this operation directly. For MSSQL see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name, postgresql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql

Comment: mysqlDB,no unipivot and Thanks for response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - turn table into different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table)

Comment: I don't think you can invert sorting of `SELECT` output (columns > rows).