# How to transform / pivot PostGres table turning column names into row entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostGres table (imported from a csv file), where a variable number of columns (after an id column) have dates as column names.

As a reduced example:

```
CREATE TABLE inputTable(id INTEGER NOT NULL,_01_Jan_2021 FLOAT, _02_Jan_2021 FLOAT, _03_Jan_2021 FLOAT);
INSERT INTO inputTable(id,_01_Jan_2021, _02_Jan_2021, _03_Jan_2021)
VALUES
(1,10.1,20.2,30.3),
(2,11.11,22.22,33.33);
```

Yielding:

```
mydb=> SELECT * FROM inputTable;
 id | _01_jan_2021 | _02_jan_2021 | _03_jan_2021
----+-------------+-------------+-------------
  1 |        10.1 |        20.2 |        30.3
  2 |       11.11 |       22.22 |       33.33
(2 rows)
```

I want to flatten these into a time-series format:

```
CREATE TABLE outputTable(id INTEGER NOT NULL,dt DATE, val FLOAT);
```

yielding:

```
mydb=> SELECT * FROM outputTable;
 id |     dt     |  val
----+------------+-------
  1 | 2021-01-01 |  10.1
  1 | 2021-01-02 |  20.2
  1 | 2021-01-03 |  30.3
  2 | 2021-01-01 | 11.11
  2 | 2021-01-02 | 22.22
  2 | 2021-01-03 | 33.33
(6 rows)
```

There will be a variable set of dates as columns in the input table, and these will change for each csv.

I can/could manipulate the CSV prior to loading (eg via Python or otherwise), but I am wondering if there is a purely SQL solution?

I can get the list of column names using:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_name='inputtable' AND column_name != 'id';
```

And for an individual column eg '_01_Jan_2021':

```
INSERT INTO outputTable(id,dt,val)
SELECT id,TO_DATE('_01_Jan_2021','_DD_MON_yyyy'),_01_Jan_2021
FROM inputTable;
```

But I am unsure how to bolt the two together and run for all columns.

EDIT: I have read the various answers to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/equivalent-to-unpivot-in-postgresql), and the use of `UNNEST()` which looks promising, but I am unclear how to move from the "most-voted" solution with hard-coded column names, to my more generic requirement where I create a list of column names on the fly (and also convert the TEXT to a DATE value).

As per the line above *"There will be a variable set of dates as columns in the input table, and these will change for each csv."*

So I can write:

```
INSERT INTO outputTable(id,dt,val)
SELECT id,
       UNNEST(ARRAY['2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-03']::DATE[] ),
       UNNEST(ARRAY[_01_Jan_2021,_02_Jan_2021,_03_Jan_2021])
FROM inputTable;
```

And I can take it a step further still with:

```
WITH cols AS(SELECT column_name AS c FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_name='inputtable' AND column_name != 'id')
INSERT INTO outputTable(id,dt,val)
SELECT id,
       UNNEST( (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(TO_DATE(c,'_DD_MON_YYYY')) FROM cols) ),
       UNNEST(ARRAY[_01_Jan_2021,_02_Jan_2021,_03_Jan_2021])
FROM inputTable;
```

but I can't find a way to dynamically-construct the 2nd `UNNEST` to create an array of column name variables, rather than an array of TEXT.