# How to get columns as row values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called **fund_flag** and it has columns like fund_type, fund1, fund2, fund3, fund4, fund5, fund6, sign_val

and table data is as follows.

| fund_type | fund1 | fund2 | fund3 | fund4 | fund5 | fund6 | sign_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SGP | Y | N | N | N | Y | N | - |
| USD | Y | N | Y | Y | Y | N | + |
| INR | N | N | Y | N | Y | Y | - |

I want output like :

| fund_type | fund_name | fund_value | sign_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SGP | fund1 | Y | - |
| SGP | fund2 | N | - |
| SGP | fund3 | N | - |
| SGP | fund4 | N | - |
| SGP | fund5 | Y | - |
| SGP | fund6 | N | - |
| USD | fund1 | Y | + |
| USD | fund2 | N | + |
| USD | fund3 | Y | + |
| USD | fund4 | Y | + |
| USD | fund5 | Y | + |
| USD | fund6 | N | + |
| in the same way for INR |  |  |  |

Please help me with the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Oracle or SQL Server this could be achieved with the UNPIVOT operator, but that is not available in Postgres. However You could use `VALUES()` and `JOIN LATERAL` to unpivot the columns :

```
select f.fund_type, t.*, f.sign_val
from fund_flag f
  cross join lateral (
     values 
       (f.fund1, 'fund1'),
       (f.fund2, 'fund2'),
       (f.fund3, 'fund3'),
       (f.fund4, 'fund4'),
       (f.fund5, 'fund5'),
       (f.fund6, 'fund6')
  ) as t(fund_name, fund_value)
order by fund_type;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XbEINoHn)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fund_type, unnest(array['fund1', 'fund2', 'fund3', 'fund4', 'fund5', 'fund6']) AS fund_name, 
                  unnest(array[fund1, fund2, fund3, fund4, fund5, fund6]) AS fund_value, sign_val
FROM fund_flag;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get your desired output.The following query will help you out to illustrate your desired output:

```
SELECT
  fund_type,
  'fund' || column_number AS fund_name,
  unnested_data.column_value AS fund_value,
  unnested_data.sign_val
FROM (
  SELECT
    fund_type,
    unnest(array[fund1, fund2, fund3, fund4, fund5, fund6]) AS column_value,
    generate_series(1, 6) AS column_number,
    sign_val
  FROM fund_flag
) AS unnested_data
ORDER BY fund_type, column_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

To unpivot a table in PostgreSQL, you can use the `UNION ALL` operator to combine multiple SELECT statements that each select a single column and add a new column to identify the original column name. For example:

```
SELECT fund_type, 'fund1' AS fund_name, fund1 AS fund_value, sign_val
FROM fund_flag
UNION ALL
SELECT fund_type, 'fund2' AS fund_name, fund2 AS fund_value, sign_val
FROM fund_flag
UNION ALL
SELECT fund_type, 'fund3' AS fund_name, fund3 AS fund_value, sign_val
FROM fund_flag
UNION ALL
SELECT fund_type, 'fund4' AS fund_name, fund4 AS fund_value, sign_val
FROM fund_flag
UNION ALL
SELECT fund_type, 'fund5' AS fund_name, fund5 AS fund_value, sign_val
FROM fund_flag
UNION ALL
SELECT fund_type, 'fund6' AS fund_name, fund6 AS fund_value, sign_val
FROM fund_flag
ORDER BY fund_type, fund_name;
```

Maybe you could refer to this question as well: [Equivalent to unpivot() in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/equivalent-to-unpivot-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Handle your labels dynamically. You can [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.9.2.2.1.1.2.1) entire records without having to hardcode the label list, [`-`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to keep only the labels you want, then [`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.4.1.2.1) to list them. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/5zoIZw6i)

```sql
select fund_type, fund_name, fund_value::bool, sign_val
from fund_flag,
jsonb_each(to_jsonb(fund_flag)-'{fund_type,sign_val}'::text[])_(fund_name,fund_value);
```

| fund_type | fund_name | fund_value | sign_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SGP | fund1 | t | - |
| SGP | fund2 | f | - |
| SGP | fund3 | f | - |
| SGP | fund4 | f | - |
| SGP | fund5 | t | - |
| SGP | fund6 | f | - |
| USD | fund1 | t | + |
| USD | fund2 | f | + |
| USD | fund3 | t | + |
| USD | fund4 | t | + |
| USD | fund5 | t | + |
| USD | fund6 | f | + |
| INR | fund1 | f | - |
| INR | fund2 | f | - |
| INR | fund3 | t | - |
| INR | fund4 | f | - |
| INR | fund5 | t | - |
| INR | fund6 | t | - |