unpivot and pivot conversion from sql server to postgres
I am trying to perforrm conversion from sqlserver script to postgres
postgres not supporting format,unpivot and pivot function is there any alternate method to convert these to postgres
select [values],
   FORMAT([1], '#,0.00') [Code 1],
   FORMAT([2], '#,0.00') [Code 2],
   FORMAT([3], '#,0.00') [code 3],
   FORMAT((ISNULL([1], 0) + ISNULL([6], 0) + ISNULL([G], 0)),'#,0.00') [all]
from (
      select ccode,
         [values],
         value
      from abc unpivot (value for [values] in ([vq], [vq1], [vq2])) unpiv
   ) src pivot (max(value) for ccode in ([1], [6], [G])) piv

need to convert above code to postgres

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/equivalent-to-unpivot-in-postgresql Does this answer your question?

This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/equivalent-to-unpivot-in-postgresql

Before we had PIVOT we used to use case expressions and UNION. Postgres also has a feature called CROSSTAB that comes from an additional module. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905

Could you please re-write the code and share
